# How to write an Efficient applicationContext.xml in spring

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I just started learning spring.
what should be avoided while writing an ApplicationContext xml file in application development using spring so that the code will be efficient? 
(what i meant is good practice that can be followed while writing ApplicationContext xml file and please don't give me a negative vote, it is a genuine doubt)

Comment: this question is too general (broad), if you have specific issue or piece of code that you might want to make more efficient that would be better

Comment: Code efficiency has little to do with Spring configuration.

Comment: check this link for best practices for spring http://www.mydeveloperconnection.com/html/SpringBP.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things to consider below are just a few things to consider

1) Modularity - we can divide applicationContext.xml module wise and import that in main applicationContext.xml 
Example : applicationContext.xml code snippest

```
<import resource="classpath:dbConfig.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:userModuleContext.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:customerModuleContext.xml"/>
```

2) Database configuration can be stored in seperated properties file and then used in applicationContext.xml using **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer**

3) Bean scope should be appropriate like prototype, singleton, request, session

singleton - means single instance per spring container. It may cause problem in clustered environment.

4) Bean Dependancy Injection should be appropriate, so that it should not cause circular dependancy like A ---> B ---> C ---> A

Many more ....

Comment: Circular deps are perfectly fine with setter injection. In fact, it is one of IoC's killer features.

Comment: @ Marko Topolnik - I Agree with you